# Unit test with Mockito : fail test with verify(mock).method()

Tags: mockito

I want to write unit test for createSocket(String host, int port) method, but I have this error messag :

### shouldCreateSocketWithHostAndPort(....ClientCertSocketFactoryTest) org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException:Argument passed to verify() is of type SSLSocketFactoryImpl and is not a mock! Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly! See the examples of correct verifications:verify(mock).someMethod();

```
public SSLSocketFactory getSslSocketFactory() {
    return sslSocketFactory;
}

public Socket createSocket(String host, int port)
        throws IOException {
    SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
    return sslSocket;
}
```

---

This my test that I Wrote :

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
sslSocketFactory = mock(SSLSocketFactory.class);
clientCertSocketFactory = new ClientCertSocketFactory();
sslSocketFactory = clientCertSocketFactory.getSslSocketFactory();   
}
```

---

```
@Test
public void shouldCreateSocketWithHostAndPort() throws Exception {
clientCertSocketFactory.createSocket(HOST, PORT);
verify(sslSocketFactory).createSocket(HOST, PORT);
}
```

---

How Can I fix this error. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is all buggered up.

The mocked ssl socket factory is never used - it's created, then replaced by the call to `getSslSocketFactory`.

Comment: Ah yes,But when i delete sslSocketFactory = clientCertSocketFactory.getSslSocketFactory(); I have this error message : Wanted but not invoked sSlSocketFactory.createSocket(MyHost,443). Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: That's because the method is never called. I think you are misunderstanding how mockito works.  What is `ClientCertSocketFactory` here?

Comment: Yes, I understand now, I have not to replace mock object by getSslSocketFactory. I found solution, instead I wrote sslSocketFactory = client Cert SocketFactory.getSslSocketFactory(); I must write clientCertSocketFactory.sslSocketFactory() = sslSocketFactory ; And the test pass.
manny thanks